# Change Apache Default Index File

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want apache2 to host `home.php` or whatever I choose as the start page  instead of `index.html`. Everything I have read says to edit the `DirectoryIndex` parameter of the `httpd.conf` file. I do not have that file anywhere. (I searched.)

I also did not have an `.htaccess` file by default. I created one and put the line `DirectoryIndex home.php` in it; I then restarted apache. Nothing chaged.

This is in my `apache2.conf` file.

`<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

I am not sure what `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` does.

These are the file contents of my `/var/www/html/.htaccess`.

`<Directory /var/www/html>
DirectoryIndex home.php
</Directory>`

When I change `AllowOverride` to `All` I receive a server error.

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to restart Apache when you set `.htaccess` files. Your directive `DirectoryIndex home.php` should work. Are you sure that `AllowOverride` in `httpd.conf` in set for this virtual host?

Comment: There is no httpd.conf

Comment: I solved this by replacing line `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` with `DirectoryIndex home.php`.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to add DirectoryIndex to your vhost configuration.

```
<Directory /foo>
    DirectoryIndex home.php
    Allow Override All
</Directory>
```

When you want to use that option ins your `.htaccess` file you have to set `AllowOverride All` in your vhost configuration. Otherwise you should get an error in your log `DirectoryIndex not allowed here`.

Comment: After playing around with it some more I can't fix it with what you are describing. I edited the original question with more info.

Comment: Like i described ;) set AllowOverride to All otherwise you .htaccess is not working.

Comment: ;) check your logs but you get an error because now your .htaccess files are read and executed ;) so debug and fix it.